# How to pass a parametr to modal window

Tags: php, yii

I have three buttons which open 1 modal window on a page:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal',)); ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4 class="text-center">Pay</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
        'type'=>'bordered condensed',
        'data'=>$model,
        'attributes'=>array(
            array(
                'type'=>'raw',
                'label'=>'Период',
                'value'=> '', // if (clicked button id is 1 value == 1 day) else if (clicked button id is 2 value == 7 days)
            ),
        ),
    ));
    ?>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'Проверить',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(

    'encodeLabel' => false,
    'label'=>'1 day',
    'type'=>'primary',

    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => '1',
        'onclick' => 'alert(this.id)',
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
    ),
)); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(

    'encodeLabel' => false,
    'label'=>'7 dayss',
    'type'=>'primary',

    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => '2',
        'onclick' => 'alert(this.id)',
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
    ),
)); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(

    'encodeLabel' => false,
    'label'=>'1 month',
    'type'=>'primary',

    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => '3',
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
    ),
)); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

How to pass the clicked button id to TbButton value?
if (clicked button id is 1 value == 1 day) else if (clicked button id is 2 value == 7 days) ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, id of elements on website need to be unique, you may want to consider using data attributes or calling those id differently.

Next thing is that only button that is submitting form is passing value with form to the server so you either need to use hidden input field or submit form by pressing that button or submit form using ajax request and attach it manually.

As I see you have put onclick event directly in element, better solution would be to put it outside in separate script tag/script file, but it is outside of your question.

What you need to do to assign value to be sent with form is to use following js to:

Assign code to input field:

`$('#length_field').val(this.id)`

or without jQuery:

`document.getElementById('length_field').value = this.id`

if you will use `data-time-length="7"` instead of id then you can do it by:

`$('#length_field').val($(this).data('time-length'))`

However it is unclear to me where you want to pass this value, what you want to do with it.